# VirtualBox Windows 98 SE not installing

Tags: macos, virtualbox, windows-98

I am using VirtualBox 4.3.12 on my macbook pro running OS 10.9.3 and trying to create a virtual machine from a Windows 98 SE ISO file I have, which is apparently bootable. Here are the settings I used:

```
---system---

Base Memory: 512MB

Boot order: CD/DVD, Hard Disk

---display---

Video Memory: 64MB

Acceleration: 2D video, 3D

---Storage---

Controller: Floppy

Floppy Device 0: Empty

Controller: IDE

IDE Primary Master: Windows 98 SE.vdi (Normal, 2.00GB)

IDE Secondary Master: [CD/DVD] windows98se.iso (625.23 mb)
```

The rest of the settings are the default settings

When I start the vm, it gives me the option to boot from a hard disk or boot from a cd-rom

If I choose boot from hard disk, It goes to a blank screen and stays there. If I choose boot from cd-rom, it takes me to another menu which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Regardless of what I choose at that menu, it just stays there, and doesn't do anything

How can I get it to operate proerly?

Comment: I would say too much memory hangs it. Choose 32 MB RAM and 4 MB video then try again.

Comment: @Cornelius the lowest amount of video RAM i can allocate is 22 MB, I think this is because I have 3D acceleration and 2D video acceleration enabled, should I disable them or try with 22 MB of video RAM?

Comment: You can disable 3D acceleration. You can't use it anyway because there are no Guest Additions drivers for Windows 98.

Comment: @Cornelius I lowered the Ram like you suggested, but it's still not working

Comment: It could be that Win98 doesn't recognize your disk and requires an additional driver. Try to lower the size of your hard disk to 300MB or so. If you need additional space (which I doubt), simply add extra disks to it. You really have to review ALL of your hardware settings and use similar hardware as was available in those days. 2GB disks didn't exist. 512MB RAM was more than the largest disks at the time... You really have to be a bit realistic.